# How to convert ArrayLIst items into json objects in Android

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I have two array List I want to convert items of array list into json objects & then add those json objects into array list.

**Json objects & array**

```
     JSONObject jobj_id=new JSONObject();
     JSONObject jobj_ans=new JSONObject();
     JSONArray qhis_jar=new JSONArray();
```

**code for converting arraylist to json**

```
 for(int i=0;i<arr_quesid.size();i++)
     {
         try {

            jobj_id.put("ques_id", arr_quesid.get(i));
            qhis_jar.put(jobj_id);
            jobj_ans.put("ans", arr_ans.get(i));
            qhis_jar.put(jobj_ans);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

But I am getting only the last element of arraylist as json objects.

```
[{"ques_id":"questionId_7"},{"ques_name":"ans_7"},{"ques_id":"questionId_7"},{"ques_name":"ans_7"},{"ques_id":"questionId_7"},{"ques_name":"ans_7"},{"ques_id":"questionId_7"},{"ques_name":"ans_7"},{"ques_id":"questionId_7"},{"ques_name":"ans_7"},{"ques_id":"questionId_7"},{"ques_name":"ans_7"},{"ques_id":"questionId_7"},{"ques_name":"ans_7"}]
```

Please tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as to create JSONArray which contains other JSONObject's:

```
for(int i=0;i<arr_quesid.size();i++)
     {      

            jobj_id=new JSONObejct(); // 
            jobj_id.put("ques_id", arr_quesid.get(i));
            qhis_jar.put(jobj_id);
            jobj_ans=new JSONObejct();
            jobj_ans.put("ans", arr_ans.get(i));
            qhis_jar.put(jobj_ans);
     }
```

because currently you are overriding values `jobj_id` and `jobj_ans` with next value that's why `qhis_jar` JSONArray contain only last values

Comment: How can give name to the Json array??

Comment: @TechGuy:  no possible to give name to JSONArray. you can give name to JSONArray by adding JSONArray to JSONObject like `JSONObject.put("array_name",qhis_jar);`

Answer (score 2):

You may use new Gson library...

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String jsonData = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

Comment: is it possible without Gson

Comment: convert to `JSONObject`. `toJson` returns a `String`